# An algorithm for inverting a soundwave

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

Hi I’m making a simple program in Objective-C and I need to get the inverse of a soundwave.
I've tried searching for an algorithm for doing this but I haven't found anything. I guess it’s more complicated than just multiplying each value with -1 :P

Here’s my code so far, I’ve cast the data to `int32_t` to be able to manipulate it:

```
int32_t* samples = (int32_t*)(sourceBuffer.mData);

for ( int i = 0; i < sourceBuffer.mDataByteSize / sizeof(int32_t); i++ )
{
    // Add algorithm here
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by -1 should work no? What output do you get? Bear in mind you won't hear ANY difference with the wave unless you layer the normal and inverted together in which case they will cancel each other out.

Comment: OK thanks. So basically I’m doing it right. I just wanted to see if I could cancel out noise from the environment through iPhone. I guess not :P